# Inverse of a partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a partitioned matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}   
0 & F^T \\       
F & R \\      
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $0$ is $k \times k$, $F$ is $n \times k$ and $R$ is $n \times n$. I would much appreciate if someone could help me find the inverse of the matrix. I have seen some formula online but they require the first entry to be non-singular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need assumptions on $F,R$. What if $F=0$, for instance?

Comment: is $R$ invertible and $F\neq 0$ ?

Comment: R is invertible and F is non zero but not invertible

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has the [alternative formula for the inverse of a partitioned matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse#Blockwise_inversion) if the leading submatrix is singular. Applied to your system, we then have

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf 0&\mathbf F^\top\\\mathbf F&\mathbf R\end{pmatrix}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}-(\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F)^{-1}&(\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F)^{-1}\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\\\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F(\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F)^{-1}&\mathbf R^{-1}-\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F(\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\mathbf F)^{-1}\mathbf F^\top\mathbf R^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves the problem.

Comment: Just a remark, you need $F^TR^{-1}F$ to be invertible for this formula to make sense.

Comment: @julen, the Wikipedia entry says as much. Reven, also look up the "Schur complement" (before copper.hat beats me to it ;)).